# how can we generate the unique combination of N-length number for Z given set of numbers

Tags: java, algorithm, combinations, permutation

lets say the input is

> int[] input =[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

i want a 4 digit number unique combination irrespective of order like below -

> `1234, 1235, 1236, 1237, 1245, 1246, 1247 etc.,`

unwanted -

> 4321, 5321, 6321, 0000, 0111 etc., // regardless of the order i want unique

etc.,

The following is tried -

> ```
>     for (int i = 0; i < E-3; i++) {
>         System.out.println(i+"::"+(i+1)+"::"+(i + 2)+"::"+(i+3));                     
>     }
>
>     for (int i = 0; i < E-3; i++) {
>
>         for (int j = i + 4; j < E; j++) {
>
>             System.out.println(i+"::"+(i+1)+"::"+(i + 2)+"::"+j);
>             System.out.println(i+"::"+(i+1)+"::"+j+"::"+(i + 3));
>             System.out.println(i+"::"+(j)+"::"+(i+2)+"::"+(i + 3));
>             System.out.println(j+"::"+(i+1)+"::"+(i+2)+"::"+(i + 3));
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

still some combinations are missing(looks like above is inefficient), can u suggest what i am missing?

Comment: Oops. This question is definitely a duplicate, but not of that one.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat i searched before posting, i didnt understand "but not of that one" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the elements of the array are unique you can do this:

```
int len = input.length();
for (int i = 0;i<len;i++) {
    for (int j = i+1;j<len;j++) {
        for (int k = j+1;k<len;k++) {
            for (int l = k+1;l<len;l++) {
                //print the numbers in order
                //digits are: input[i] input[j] input[k] input[l]
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This will make the numbers unique regardless of order, I think the correct terminology is a permutation(this is a permutation) vs. a combination.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight You don't need that, but I realized just now I need to index into the array not print the numbers out, that way the solution is more general

Comment: @dasblinkenlight fixed it, if you take the digits from the array the solution is more general IMO

Comment: @dasblinkenlight thank you I hate people who, are quick to DV because of simple mistakes

Comment: If i want to generalize the above logic for combination of 3 / 4 / 5.. what can we do?

Comment: @Vamsi you mean the digits are 3 4 5

Comment: no, length of the value is 3 digits, 4 digits and etc. 3digits - 123,345,etc;  4digit-as in question; 5 digit-12345, 23456 etc

Comment: @Vamsi as long as you fill the array with a set of unique numbers it will work

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a recurrence algorithm to this problem, and am not sure it is grammatical in java, so take this as pseudo-code.

```
perm(int input[],int output[],int len,int num,int j,int k)
{
    int i;
    if(k==SUM) { //SUM = 4
        //print the numbers in output[0...SUM-1]
        //return
    }
    for(i=j;i<=len-num;i++) {
        output[k] =input[i];
        perm(input,output,len,num-1,i+1,k+1);
    }
}
```

in the beginning,

```
int input[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
int output[4];
perm(input,output,7,4,0,0);
```